# No sound in Blender, what do I do?

Tags: audio

Out of a sudden sound in my project disappeared. How can I debug this? Volume is okay, the clip is not muted. It happened after a crash. I have sound in the same version of blender, in a fresh project, when I drag and drop an audio file onto Video Sequencer, but not in my current project? Please help, where should I check for some settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have Mute ticked on in Playback. To fix it, you have non-standard workspaces setup, so you need to do the following:

Switch to Compositing workspace (top of viewport)

Open Playback menu (towards bottom left of viewport)

Untick Mute in Audio section (towards top of menu)

[image]

Comment: Hey, I like the look of those "squiggly" pointer arrows. Just out of curiosity, may I ask what program you used to achieve them?